# Unable to extract the table from API using python

Tags: python, api

I am trying to extract a table using an API but I am unable to do so. I am pretty sure that I am not using it correctly, and any help would be appreciated.

Actually I am trying to extract a table from this API but unable to figure out the right way on how to do it. This is what is mentioned in the website. I want to extract Latest_full_data table.

[image]

This is my code to get the table but I am getting error:

```py
import urllib
import requests
import urllib.request

locu_api = 'api_Key'

def locu_search(query):
    api_key = locu_api
    url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI/metadata?api_key=' + api_key
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    json_obj = str(response, 'utf-8')
    datanew = json.loads(json_obj)
    return datanew
```

When I do print(datanew). Update: ***Even if I change it to return data new, error is still the same.*** 
     I am getting this below error: 
    name 'datanew' is not defined

Comment: Could you add more info? Where you try to print? I see typos before (`responsen` vs `response`). Please correct the format. You lost spaces. Maybe`datanew` is inside function (I don't know, there are no indents) and you try yo print it outside the function.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for the information..I tried doing that .. error is still the same..

Comment: @rysson Thank You for the information.. I changed responsen to response.. error is same... Yes data new is inside the function.. if I make it outside I get the indentation error

Comment: @Avi, now we can see code. Please use indents next time. And look for @snakecharmerb comments. The best solutions is in *Dániel Bencze* answer, use it. You can add `datanew = locu_search()` at the bottom and then print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issues with urrlib before. If possible, try to use requests it's a better designed and working library in my opinion. Also, it is capable of reading JSON with a single function so no need to run it through multiple lines Sample code here:

```
import requests

locu_api = 'api_Key'

def locu_search():
   url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI/metadata?api_key=' + api_key
   return requests.get(url).json()

locu_search()
```

**Edit:**
The endpoint that you are calling might not be the correct one. I think you are looking for the following one:

```
import requests

api_key = 'your_api_key_here'

def locu_search(dataset_code):
   url = f'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/{dataset_code}/metadata.json?api_key={api_key}'
   req = requests.get(url)
   return req.json()

data = locu_search("FB")
```

This will return with all the metadata regarding a company. In this case Facebook.

Comment: thank you for your time and response. However I am still getting the error while calling the function:    I used the same way  you have provided the code and added this to next lines   result = locu_search(query)
print(result) .. this is the error name 'query' is not defined

Comment: In that case, you either need to define the query variable before calling the function or remove it. I have edited my answer with a working minimalistic code which you will be able to build on.

Comment: I guess it is problem with the data I guess then .. still I am getting this error ..JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) is the error I am getting.. will accept the answer and close it ..Thank you for your help !

Comment: I have also checked a couple of things. So the request returns bytes and not JSON with a 500 status code. That means that either the endpoint you are calling doesn't exist or there is something wrong with their API. The actual return message is the following  `b"Error - QEMx01 : We're sorry, but there's been an unexpected error in the system. If you continue to have problems, please contact us at connect@quandl.com."`

Comment: I have also added a new solution to my answer. I believe your error is simply due to calling the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't apply to your specific problem, but what I normally do is the following:

```
import requests

def get_values(url):
   response = requests.get(url).text
   values = json.loads(response)
   return values
```

Comment: @Xerox_04..thank you for your time and response but I am still getting the error while calling the function.. result = get_values(values)
print(result) name 'values' is not defined